# Problem With DAE parser augmented Reality

Tags: actionscript-3, papervision3d, augmented-reality

I tried everything but no success.I am having big problems in importing files.So many error.... spent 5 hours but nothing. I successfully able to create project using collada parser but all the problems are coming when i am using import org.papervision3d.objects.parsers.DAE; There were some files missing and when i tried to download the missing files then it is showing me errors in files that i downloaded. Please suggest me how to get solve it.I wonder w'd it be possible for anyone to upload the configuration of papervision+libspark+ascollada which you used for creating a demo(like Brian Hodge used). Thanks alot in advance.And i am extremely sorry for posting this question in a thread AS3 DAE Augmented Reality PaperVision 3D as an answere.I am new to this forum and havent noticed the question tag.Extremely sorry...

Answer (score 0):

The following is a link to a rather large explanation on PV3D/Flar toolkit AR

[AS3 DAE Augmented Reality PaperVision 3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673059/as3-dae-augmented-reality-papervision-3d)

### -Questions

What IDE are you developing in?  Flex Builder 3, Flash Develop, and Flash CS4 are all capable of handling embeds utilizing the Flex 3 SDK, BUT, Adobe Flash CS3 does not allow you to used embed and will not recognize it.

### -Flash CS3 produces the following

```
TypeError: Error #1007: Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor.
at Untitled_fla::MainTimeline/Untitled_fla::frame1()
```

### -The Following works in all the others listed above

```
[Embed(source="foo.jpg")]  //<---  NO SEMICOLON OR BREAKS
private var foo:Class;

var testFoo:Bitmap = new foo();
```

### -Important

One thing that I would like to note, notice there is no semicolon on the embed line!

Hope this helps, apparently the original poster figured his/her problem out, but wanted to answer sid.