# Error parsing .dae,Error#1009 in flash player,Augmented Reality flash

Tags: flash, papervision3d, augmented-reality

Whenever I am trying to use an animate.dae file(I am creating small project using flartoolkit+papervision3d+ascollada) .The flash player is reporting me the errors pasted below.If I am pressing continue then I can see my .dae file but without animation :(
And Please note that I am not using any heavy animation.

ERROR:

> ```
> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
>
> at org.papervision3d.objects.parsers::DAE/buildAnimationChannels()[C:\..\org\papervision3d\objects\parsers\DAE.as:657]
>
> at org.papervision3d.objects.parsers::DAE/onParseAnimationsComplete()[C:\..\org\papervision3d\objects\parsers\DAE.as:1722]
>
> at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
>
> at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
>
> at org.ascollada.io::DaeReader/loadNextAnimation()[C:\..\Libs\org\ascollada\io\DaeReader.as:169]
>
> at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
>
> at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
> ```

Comment: This will be a problem with how papervision is reading the dae. Sorry I can't help, but anyway it's nothing to do with the Flash player per se.

Answer (score 0):

Fenomas is right, this has to do with how the COLLADA data was made.  There is some very specific work arounds that can be used to help cleanup the XML which is all COLLADA/DAE is.

I touched deeply on this all [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673059/as3-dae-augmented-reality-papervision-3d).

Some people use things like Milk Shape 3D, or even Swift3D to export their XML.  What I have found through my travels is that native COLLADA exporters from MAYA and MAX fail terribly.  If your using 2008 version of either of the formerly named software, [feelingsoftware.com](http://www.feelingsoftware.com) makes a wonderful COLLADA(DAE) exporter that papervision loves!

Comment: Hi Brian,
Thanks for your help. I used Google sketch up and now the same code works Fine :) I have one more question.When i am trying to use lazy rendering engine then i cannot see the image. How you go about this problem.I know that the problem is regarding with the positioning and rotation but its hard to judge the exact location of image at runtime. Any suggestions to solve this problem in easier way.